# CodeIgniter SQL query - how to sum values for each month?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following table:

```
//table_1

record_id   user_id    plant_id    date        cost
1           1          1           2011-03-01   10
2           1          1           2011-03-02   10
3           1          1           2011-04-10   5
4           1          2           2011-04-15   5
```

I would like to build a query (if possible using CI Active Records, but MySQL is fine) in which I generate the following result:

```
[1] => [1] => [March 2011] [20]

           => [April 2011] [5]

       [2] => [March 2011] [0]

           => [April 2011] [5]
```

I have tried using `$this->db->group_by` but I think I'm not using it correctly.

If anyone could give me a pointer or roadmap to get this done it would be much appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample table

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t( record_id int, user_id int, plant_id int, date datetime, cost float);
insert t select
1 ,1, 1 ,'2011-03-01', 10 union all select
2 ,1, 1 ,'2011-03-02', 10 union all select
3 ,1, 1 ,'2011-04-10', 5 union all select
4 ,1, 2 ,'2011-04-15', 5;
```

Because you want to see the row with 0, you need to do a cross join between the year-month and all user-plants.

```
select up.user_id, up.plant_id, ym2, ifnull(sum(t.cost),0) totalcost
from (select distinct date_format(date, '%Y-%m') ym, date_format(date, '%M %Y') ym2 from t) dates
cross join (select distinct t.user_id, t.plant_id from t) up
left join t on date_format(t.date, '%Y-%m') = dates.ym
           and up.user_id=t.user_id
            and up.plant_id=t.plant_id
group by up.user_id, up.plant_id, ym2, ym
order by up.user_id, up.plant_id, date(concat(ym,'-1'));
```

The fact that `Month Year` does not sort correctly also requires the complex treatment of the dates for ordering purposes at the end.

Comment: @cyberkiwi -- holysh*t! that code is way over my head but it works beautifully on my terminal -- I think I'll run some variation of it as raw SQL since I don't think there's a way to fully port to CI ActiveRecords -- thanks a bunch!

Comment: actually it's just a matter of enclosing the SQL code above in $this->db->query("code") -- thanks again for your help

Comment: @cyberkiwi - if there's an additional column called `category`, and I'd like to filter only results with `category = 1` -- where should I insert a `where` clause in your code above?

Comment: @torr before the group by `AND category....` and possibly also inside the subquery aliased as `up`, a `..t.plant_id from t where ...) up`

Comment: @ck - absolutely perfect! I posted another question based on your code above, because I need to join another table -- if you have the time, should be some easy points for you! => [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399546/how-to-join-a-table-to-this-sql-code) -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty intense way to do it and it would be far preferable to store the month-year as a column itself if you need to make these queries frequently, but this is basically how it works:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date), ' ', YEAR(date)) AS monthyear, COUNT(*) AS count GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), plant_id;
```

That should get you the resultset you're looking for.

Comment: thanks @michael - would `monthyear` be a new empty column in the table where the `CONCAT` would store its result? or would `monthyear` be a column populated when the user enters his plant data?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't quite clear. The query above requires no modification to the table itself. However, the concept of using a new field would reduce some of the strain on the DB. Basically, you'd create a column called "month" with a type of DATE, which you would just populate on INSERT. It's value would be `CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()), '-01')`

Comment: mctiernan -- your solution seems simpler to execute than @ck's above, so I'm interested in what you have to say -- but i can't get it to run on my terminal -- say i'm using the table @ck proposed above -- when I run your SQL, i get an error near `GROUP BY YEAR(date) MONTH(date), plant_id` -- is there anything I am missing? do I need to add any fields before running your code?

Comment: Haha. Well, if you're directly copying and pasting, I totally forgot **the table** from my select query (which is pretty embarrassing. It should be `SELECT ... FROM table_1 GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), plant_id`

Comment: you're right - now it runs but the result is not what i expected - it gives me `March 2011 - 2` `April 2011 - 1` `April 2011 - 1` -- so the issue is that it repeats April and is counting the number of events instead of summing the `cost` field for each month