# How to join a table to this SQL code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, join

I am using this awesome code from *[@Richard aka cyberkiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573261/richard-aka-cyberkiwi)* to run a query (it returns the sum of `value` for each month, for each plant):

**table name: data**

```
record_id   id_fk    plant_id_fk    date         value   category_1
1           1          1            2011-03-01   10      A
2           1          1            2011-03-02   10      A
3           1          1            2011-04-10   5       B
4           1          2            2011-04-15   5       C
```

**SQL code**

```
    select up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, ym2, ifnull(sum(data.value_1),0) totalvalue_1
    from (select distinct date_format(date, '%Y-%m') ym, date_format(date, '%M %Y') ym2 from data) dates
    cross join (select distinct data.id_fk, data.plant_id_fk from data) up
    left join data on date_format(data.date, '%Y-%m') = dates.ym
        and up.id_fk=data.id_fk
        and up.plant_id_fk=data.plant_id_fk
        and category_1='A'
    group by up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, ym2, ym
    order by up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, date(concat(ym,'-1'))
```

Now I need to join this with the following table in order to run a PHP loop that will retrieve the `plant_name` instead of the `plant_id`.

**table name: plants**

```
id_fk    plant_id      plant_name
1        1             oak tree
1        2             cherry tree
```

Anyone know where to insert the clause that would create this join?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified as shown below

> select
>            up.id_fk,
>            **p.plant_name,**
>
>            ym2,
>            ifnull(sum(data.value_1),0) totalvalue_1
>       from (
>            select distinct date_format(date, '%Y-%m') ym, date_format(date, '%M %Y') ym2
>            from data) dates
>       cross join (
>            select distinct data.id_fk, data.plant_id_fk
>            from data) up
>       **inner join plants p on p.plant_id = up.plant_id_fk**
>
>       left join data
>             on date_format(data.date, '%Y-%m') = dates.ym
>             and up.id_fk=data.id_fk
>             and up.plant_id_fk=data.plant_id_fk
>             and category_1='A'
>       group by up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, ym2, ym, **p.plant_name**
>
>       order by up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, date(concat(ym,'-1'))

Comment: thanks @ck -- once again you saved the day! code works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I don't think the recordset and the query are matching; I don't see the field record_id from the fieldset.  I will adjust the query you provided.

```
select up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, pn.plant_name, ym2, ifnull(sum(data.value_1),0) totalvalue_1
    from (select distinct date_format(date, '%Y-%m') ym, date_format(date, '%M %Y') ym2 from data) dates
    cross join (select distinct data.id_fk, data.plant_id_fk from data) up
    left join data on date_format(data.date, '%Y-%m') = dates.ym
        and up.id_fk=data.id_fk
        and up.plant_id_fk=data.plant_id_fk
        and category_1='A'
    INNER JOIN plants pn ON up.plant_id_fk = pn.plant_id
    group by up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, ym2, ym
    order by up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk, date(concat(ym,'-1'))
```

This should work.  I added the pn.plant_name to the SELECT area, and used a INNER JOIN to join the plants table to the up selection for the field plant_id_fk.

As an aside, it makes it a lot easier to read if the SQL elements are capitalized (SELECT, JOIN, GROUP etc) as well as your table definitions (UP, YM2, YM, DATES etc etc).  This is just my personal preference.

Nishan Karassik
www.medfocusrcm.com

Comment: @user672210 thanks for pitching in - I think your solution is similar to @ck's above

Comment: It's standard practice update your profile with your name and site, rather than signing off. But thanks for contributing nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Just before the group by

```
left join plants on data.id_fk=plants.id_fk and data.plant_id_fk=plants.plant_id
```

and then replace in the group by and select {up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk} by plant.plant_name

Comment: thanks @pcofre -- I tried @ck's suggestion above and it works - will try yours as well -- much appreciated

Comment: just FYI, for some reason your suggested code does not return all the expected values